# HP ProLiant ML110 G7 Difficulty Loading OpenSUSE Leap

Tags: hp-proliant, opensuse, raid10

I am having a problem with the HP Proliant ML110 G7.  I am trying to load OPenSUSE Leap.  I go through the whole installation. It is supposed to detect and load all drivers required.  The ML100 G7 has a SmartRAID B110i controller card.

32GB RAM
(4) disks (2) TB each

I loaded the OpenSUSE Leap from a CD.  I go through all the menus.  I have tried configuring the RAID 1+0 and designating the RAID configs and then I have tried loading the OpenSUSE Leap without doing the RAID set up only to get the same result that it would not boot from the Hard Drive and goes to GRUB recovery mode.

I have tried to disable the  SmartRAID B110i but then can't get anything to work properly.  I have tried several different ways to get it to work but nothing will work.  The RAID controller has a Logical Drive created but OpenSUSE does not see it and offers to create RAID drives.  I am not sure if I need to manually load the drivers but OpenSUSE is not giving me this option.  OpenSUSE is not giving me any warnings or saying that the ML 110 G7 is not compatable during the installation or giving me the opportunity to load HP ProLiant drivers.

Has anyone experienced this or has a procedure to get OpenSUSE to load would be great.  If I just disable the B110i RAID Controller and just use the virtual one create by OpenSUE?

Just looking for solutions to get it to load and run.

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Fd7.jpg)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dead end of life hardware platform.

Answer (score 0):

The B110i controller is not a true HW controller, and is not compatible with most Linux distributions. In order to install Linux on this server, it is recommended to delete any existing RAID arrays.

How to manage RAID using ORCA - https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=kc0105084en_us

Boot the server with the OpenSuSE image, and install the OS on one of the drives.

Once the installation is done, ensure the boot device and boot order is set correctly in BIOS.

HP Smart Array B110i SATA RAID Controller - Enabling the Controller and Setting the Boot Order - https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=c01876989

Comment: Please, always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. You can take a look at [How do I write a good answer ?](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer)